# Scraping a complex table using Beautifulsoup and Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_grdUsers2" style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tbody><tr class="listHeader">
                        <th scope="col" style="width:11%;">Name</th><th scope="col" style="width:12%;">Password</th><th scope="col" style="width:16%;">Rights</th><th scope="col" style="width:10%;">Bureaus</th><th scope="col" style="width:15%;">FullName</th><th scope="col" style="width:16%;">Email</th><th scope="col" style="width:12%;">Status</th><th scope="col" style="width:12%;">Logon Tries</th>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td>user1</td><td align="center">
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$txtManageUsersPassword" type="text" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersPassword_0" style="width: 95%; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$ddlManageUsersRights" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_ddlManageUsersRights_0" style="width:95%;">
                            <option value="User">User</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
                            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                            <option value="Child Supervisor">Child Supervisor</option>

                        </select>

                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$ddlManageUsersBureaus" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_ddlManageUsersBureaus_0" style="width:95%;">
                            <option value="255">High</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="128">Medium</option>
                            <option value="0">Low</option>

                        </select>

                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$txtManageUsersFullName" type="text" value="First1 Last1" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersFullName_0" style="width: 95%; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$txtManageUsersEmail" type="text" value="user1@company.com" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersEmail_0" style="width: 95%; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$ddlManageUsersStatus" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_ddlManageUsersStatus_0" style="width:95%;">
                            <option value="Active">Active</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                            <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>

                        </select>

                                                </td><td align="center">                                                    
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl02$txtManageUsersLogonTries" type="text" value="0" maxlength="1" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersLogonTries_0" style="width:95%;">
                                                </td>
                    </tr><tr style="background-color:#CED6E7;">
                        <td>user2</td><td align="center">
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$txtManageUsersPassword" type="text" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersPassword_1" style="background-color: rgb(206, 214, 231); width: 95%; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$ddlManageUsersRights" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_ddlManageUsersRights_1" style="background-color:#CED6E7;width:95%;">
                            <option value="User">User</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
                            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                            <option value="Child Supervisor">Child Supervisor</option>

                        </select>

                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$ddlManageUsersBureaus" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_ddlManageUsersBureaus_1" style="background-color:#CED6E7;width:95%;">
                            <option value="255">High</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="128">Medium</option>
                            <option value="0">Low</option>

                        </select>

                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$txtManageUsersFullName" type="text" value="First2 Last2" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersFullName_1" style="background-color: rgb(206, 214, 231); width: 95%; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAUBJREFUOBGVVE2ORUAQLvIS4gwzEysHkHgnkMiEc4zEJXCMNwtWTmDh3UGcYoaFhZUFCzFVnu4wIaiE+vvq6+6qTgthGH6O4/jA7x1OiCAIPwj7CoLgSXDxSjEVzAt9k01CBKdWfsFf/2WNuEwc2YqigKZpK9glAlVVwTTNbQJZlnlCkiTAZnF/mePB2biRdhwHdF2HJEmgaRrwPA+qqoI4jle5/8XkXzrCFoHg+/5ICdpm13UTho7Q9/0WnsfwiL/ouHwHrJgQR8WEwVG+oXpMPaDAkdzvd7AsC8qyhCiKJjiRnCKwbRsMw9hcQ5zv9maSBeu6hjRNYRgGFuKaCNwjkjzPoSiK1d1gDDecQobOBwswzabD/D3Np7AHOIrvNpHmPI+Kc2RZBm3bcp8wuwSIot7QQ0PznoR6wYSK0Xb/AGVLcWwc7Ng3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$txtManageUsersEmail" type="text" value="user2@company.com" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersEmail_1" style="background-color: rgb(206, 214, 231); width: 95%; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td><td align="center">
                                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$ddlManageUsersStatus" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_ddlManageUsersStatus_1" style="background-color:#CED6E7;width:95%;">
                            <option selected="selected" value="Active">Active</option>
                            <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                            <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>

                        </select>

                                                </td><td align="center">                                                    
                                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grdUsers2$ctl03$txtManageUsersLogonTries" type="text" value="0" maxlength="1" id="MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersLogonTries_1" style="background-color:#CED6E7;width:95%;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to scrape a table that contains text, dropdown options, and values. The result would look:
user1 | Supervisor | Medium | First1 Last1 | user1@company.com | Inactive

user2 | Supervisor | Medium | First2 Last2 | user2@company.com | Active

Intended to be outputted to csv. So far I have:

```
headers = [c.get_text(strip=True) for c in soup.find('tr', attrs={'class':'listHeader'}).findAll('th')]

#find_all doesn't work here it just grabs one
for table in soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'MainContent_grdUsers2'}):
        try:
            column3=(table.find("option", attrs={"selected": "selected"}).get('value')) 
        except:
            continue

#this only grabs a specific cell
for table in soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'MainContent_grdUsers2'}):
        try:
            column6=(table.find("input", attrs={"id": "MainContent_grdUsers2_txtManageUsersEmail_0"}).get('value')) 
        except:
            continue
```

I can go in and individually grab the cells I want but there are around 100 rows of records in this table and I am finding it difficult to figure out how to grab it all at once since there isn't just text, but dropdown option values, and values. Is there a way to do this with Beautifulsoup? I tried briefly with pandas and lxml but I have never used those before.

Updated code:

```
headers = [c.get_text(strip=True) for c in soup.find('tr', attrs={'class':'listHeader'}).findAll('th')]
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'MainContent_grdUsers2'})
data = []

for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:] : 
    td = tr.find_all('td') 
    try : 
        data += [ 
            [ 
                td[0].getText() , 
                td[2].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(), 
                td[3].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(),
                td[4].find('input').get('value'),
                    if value is None:
                        continue
                td[5].find('input').get('value'),
                td[6].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText()
            ] 
        ]
    except Exception as ex : 
        #print(ex)  ## you can uncomment this line for debugging ##
        continue

for row in data : 
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the html you provided, this should work :

```
if soup.find('tr', attrs={'class':'listHeader'}) : 
    headers = [ 
        'none' if c is None else c.get_text(strip=True) 
        for c in soup.find('tr', attrs={'class':'listHeader'}).findAll('th') 
    ]
else : 
    headers = None

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'MainContent_grdUsers2'})
data = []

for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:] : 
    td = tr.find_all('td') 
    try : 
        data += [ 
            [ 
                td[0].getText() , 
                td[2].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(), 
                td[3].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(), 
                td[4].find('input').get('value'),  
                td[5].find('input').get('value'),
                td[6].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText()
            ] 
        ]
    except Exception as ex : 
        #print(ex)  ## you can uncomment this line for debugging ##
        continue

for row in data : 
    print(' '.join(str(r) for r in row))
```

Output:

```
user1 Supervisor Medium First1 Last1 user1@company.com Inactive
user2 Supervisor Medium First2 Last2 user2@company.com Active
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm getting a NoneType error: td[2].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Comment: Can you give me the url or the entire html table ?

Comment: It is too large to include in the question, is there any other way I can clarify for you?

Comment: I updated the code to catch all exceptions, try again .

Comment: This works now. Thank you. It does however throw an error if it comes across a blank cell. How can I fix this? Something like:     if 'value' == ' ' 
 continue ?

Comment: Yes, you can try `if value == '' : continue` or `if value is None : continue` , depending on the `value` . If you still get errors , please give me an example of your input and code

Comment: I've update with the new code, getting syntax error. I don't think I've placed the if statement in the correct place.

Comment: Ok, i made a few adjustments , copy - paste my code and try again ( I assume you get errors when you try to print the `data` )

Comment: Error free now. The headers do no generate now though. That is okay though I will try to append my own headers when outputting to csv. Thank you.