# Splitting data parsed by Beautifulsoup into csv columns

Tags: python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'MainContent_grdUsers2'})
data = []

for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:] : 
    td = tr.find_all('td') 
    try : 
        data += [ 
            [ 
                td[0].getText() , 
                td[2].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(), 
                td[3].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText(), 
                td[4].find('input').get('value'),  
                td[5].find('input').get('value'),
                td[6].find('option', {'selected':'selected'}).getText()
            ] 
        ]
    except Exception as ex : 
        print(ex)  
        continue


with open('test5.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data : 
        writer.writerow([' '.join(str(r) for r in row)])
```

I am trying to parse a complex html table to csv. This code works and grabs the desired data but each row is contained in one cell instead of separate columns for each of the 6 values per row. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's always a good idea to include a sample of the input data, if possible. I assume you are using the same data as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/43396370/2997179?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily setting `newline=''` and joining the table cells with spaces. Your data appears to be in a suitable format to be passed directly to `writer.writerows()`.

```
with open('test5.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    header = ['Name', 'Rights', 'Bureaus', 'FullName', 'Email', 'Status']
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: It does need `newline=''` otherwise it skips a line in between rows but passing directly to `writer.writerows()` works as desired. Thanks for the simple solution I should have tried that first.